# What is better to return: null or false?

Tags: php, function, null

So i have function for sign up:

```
<?php   

function sign_up($login, $password, $email){
global $db;

if(is_login_exist($login)){
    return ['error' => 'Login already exists', 'result' => null];
}

if(is_email_exist($email)){
    return ['error' => 'Email already exists', 'result' => null];
}

//hash password
$password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => 12]);
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (login, password, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

//add check
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $login, $password, $email);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
return ['error' => null, 'result' => 'success']; 
}?>
```

So if i have for example error when login already exist i return associative array ['error' => 'Login already exists', 'result' => null]

**Question:** Is it right to return 'result' parameter as null or as false?

Answer (score 0):

I would return:
`status => 'ok'/'error'` and optional `'error_message' => 'message'` and `'error_code' => 0` whenever the status is error. But this is just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I would throw an Exception if there were a problem.

```
function sign_up(mysqli $db, $login, $password, $email){
    // hash password
    $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => 12]);
    // try to insert
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (login, password, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $login, $password, $email);
    $stmt->execute();

    return true; 
}
```

Requirements:

- mysqli is set to throw exceptions if there's an error => `mysqli_report()`
- there is a `UNIQUE` constraint on the `login` and `email` fields